# React.JS - changing input based on another input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change value of input field based on another one and vice versa.

That's create issue, any changed value not displayed in input. Anything I type is not show by input field.

Following which I tried, You can see I am trying to change value of input 1 based on 2 and 2nd input value based on first:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  
   useEffect(() => {
   
   //fetch api call here
   
   });

  const [firstVal, setFirstVal] = useState(0);
  const [secondVal, setSecondVal] = useState(0);
  
  const changeFirstValue = (e) => {
      setSecondVal(e.target.value / 2);
  }

  const changeSecondValue = (e) => {
      setFirstVal(e.target.value * 2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='number' value={firstVal} onChange={changeFirstValue}></input>
      <input type='number' value={secondVal} onChange={changeSecondValue}></input>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want those two input values to keep the **2 times** relationship, no matter which is inputting?

Comment: @Sorry, I edited my question. I want change 2nd value on first change and first value on second change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the division and multiplication relationship between these two elements. Try below code:

```
  const changeFirstValue = (e) => {
    setSecondVal(e.target.value);
    setFirstVal(e.target.value * 2);
  }

  const changeSecondValue = (e) => {
      setFirstVal(e.target.value);
      setSecondVal(e.target.value / 2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='number' value={firstVal} onChange={changeSecondValue}></input>
      <input type='number' value={secondVal} onChange={changeFirstValue}></input>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: @ketan It works for me 
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mendeleev-21gec?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I think you have to reverse the call of the two functions,
so your code will look like this:

```
...
 <input type='number' value={firstVal} onChange={changeSecondValue}></input>
 <input type='number' value={secondVal} onChange={changeFirstValue}></input>
...
```